# How to echo INNER join in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have tested my code in MySQL, and it works. My only problem is that I do not understand how I echo an INNER JOIN (never used it before), and I can't seem to find clear examples online.

*I need to echo the code into a `<table>`
connection to the database (works)*:

```
include 'db_connection1.php';

$conn = OpenCon();

echo "Connected Successfully";
```

What the database connection goes to:

```
<?php
    function OpenCon()
    {
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "admin";
        $db = "theDBname";

        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or
            die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

        return $conn;
    }

    function CloseCon($conn)
    {
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT orders.Order_ID AS OrderID,
            customer.First_Name AS FirstName,
            customer.Last_Name AS LastName,
            orders.Order_Date AS OrderDate
            FROM Orders
            INNER JOIN customer ON orders.Customer_Customer_ID=customer.Customer_ID";
```

[image]

Comment: `echo $sql;`? It's really unclear what you're asking here

Comment: If you mean "how do I echo the result from an associative array containing the result of the query", the `JOIN` is irrelevant, as you're giving an alias to the field you're selecting.

Comment: What do you mean by `Echo an INNER JOIN`? You mean to echo entire query?

Comment: Yes, I need to display that code in a php webpage, so i guess echo the entire query

Comment: @Lagartist so what you're saying is that you want to display the **results** of the query in a table?

Comment: Now that you've edited your question there are more questions for you. Do you already have a connection from PHP to the DB? Do you know how to execute queries using PHP? Can you show us all your relevant code?

Comment: @nick Yes exactly, I have done it with just one table before never joining two

Comment: @waterloomatt Already have a connection to DB, have included it above for you and thats all my code, I understand a little bit about how to execute them since my other php pages that only select from one DB table work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment if you want to display the query in the content simply do;

```
echo $sql;
```

(I know this isn't much of an answer - this is a formality to have it written down)

**EDIT AFTER EXPLANATION**

From your comment, you want the results in a table?
So...

```
<?php

$table = "<table><tr><th>Order ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Order Date</th></tr>";

// Set up DB connection
$conn = new MySqli("db_hostname", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");
// Excecute the query
$result = $conn->query("SELECT orders.Order_ID AS OrderID,
    customer.First_Name AS FirstName, 
    customer.Last_Name AS LastName,
    orders.Order_Date AS OrderDate
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.Customer_Customer_ID=customer.Customer_ID");
// For each row, add the results to a table string using concatenate (.=)
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['OrderID']}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['FirstName']}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['LastName']}</td>";
    $table .= "<td>{$row['OrderDate']}</td>";
    $table .= "</tr>";
}

$table .= "</table";
print $table;
```

Comment: okay, sorry I'm explaining what I want to do poorly, I should say that I want to put it in a table, sorry

Comment: i think he wants to run the query and display the results in a table. usual stuff

Comment: Thank you @SamSwift웃 thats it but i get the error of "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in 'fllename' Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in "

Comment: Going by your displayed DB Structure - your query (the one I copied) will have failed - your join matches columns that don't exist. You'll need to resolve that for this to work

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much for the help, I'll tinker around with it now

Comment: Awesome - if this helped resolve your issue, please consider marking as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your orders table doesn't appear to have a column called `Customer_Customer_ID`. So I've no idea how you claim the query works.

However, add a column `Customer_ID`, and tweak that last line to:

```
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.Customer_ID=customer.Customer_ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand how I Echo an INNER JOIN

The important concept here is that an INNER JOIN (or any join for that matter) returns in the same result set. You can get many rows but that isn't determined by using a join or not. You can simply loop over the result set; each iteration is 1 row.

```
<?php
...
$results = $conn->query("SELECT orders.Order_ID AS OrderID,
    customer.First_Name AS FirstName, 
    customer.Last_Name AS LastName,
    orders.Order_Date AS OrderDate
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN customer ON orders.Customer_Customer_ID = 
    customer.Customer_ID");

print '<table border="1">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["OrderID"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["FirstName"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["LastName"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["OrderDate"].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';
```

Comment: Apologies for using `print` instead of `echo`; it burns my eyes too. I took it from here - https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage#select-multiple-records-as-associative-array